# Getting the error Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, null, classpath

I'm getting the following error (below), and i have tried a lot of things like change the local to call the method localizacao.setId(usuario.recuperarId()), later tried to instanciety the class usuario alone and not this not solved, this is giving me a hard work to solve, if someone can help i'll be grateful

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

### The error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.znovations.citty, PID: 4666
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(DatabaseReference.java:96)
        at com.znovations.citty.model.Usuario.recuperarId(Usuario.java:34)
        at com.znovations.citty.activitys.MapsActivity.onMapReady(MapsActivity.java:84)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzat.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.0.0:3)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
        at dy.aZ(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214515084@21.45.15 (150700-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bk.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@214515084@21.45.15 (150700-0):1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

### MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ActivityMapaBinding binding;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private LatLng localizacaoAtual;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMapaBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //Configuracoes inciais
        autenticacao = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        configurarToolbar();


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Recuperar localização do usuário
        recuperarLocalizacaoUsuario();

        localizacao.setId(usuario.recuperarId());
        localizacao.salvarLocalizacao();

    }

    public void clicarMapa(){
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                mMap.addMarker(
                        new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title("Local de experiencia")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.cranio))

                );
            }
        });
    }

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    UsuarioLocalizacao localizacao = new UsuarioLocalizacao();

    private void recuperarLocalizacaoUsuario() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
               localizacaoAtual = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                localizacao.setLatitude(String.valueOf(localizacaoAtual.latitude));
                localizacao.setLongitude(String.valueOf(localizacaoAtual.longitude));

                clicarMapa();
                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(
                        new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(localizacaoAtual)
                                .title("Meu local")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.usuario))
                );

                mMap.moveCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(localizacaoAtual, 15)
                );
            }

        };



        //Solicitar atualizações de localização
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    10000,
                    10,
                    locationListener
            );
        }

    }

    public void configurarToolbar(){
        toolbar.setTitle("Encontrar");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()){

                    case R.id.menuSair:
                        autenticacao.signOut();
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void deslogarUsuario(){
        autenticacao.signOut();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.menuSair:
                autenticacao.signOut();
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

### UsuarioLocalizacao class

```
public class UsuarioLocalizacao {

    private String id;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public UsuarioLocalizacao() {

    }

    public void salvarLocalizacao(){
        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        DatabaseReference user = firebaseRef.child(String.valueOf("Localizacao")).child(getId());

        user.setValue(this);
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

### Usuario class

```
public class Usuario {

    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private String Email;
    private String senha;
    private String idSalvo;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public void salvar(){
        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        DatabaseReference user = firebaseRef.child("usuarios").child( getId());

        user.setValue(this);
    }

    public String recuperarId(){
        DatabaseReference referencia = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
        referencia.child("usuarios")
                .child(getId()).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    idSalvo = String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue());
                }
            }
        });

        return idSalvo;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    @Exclude
    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from this method:

```
public String recuperarId(){
    DatabaseReference referencia = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    referencia.child("usuarios")
            .child(getId()).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                idSalvo = String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue());
            }
        }
    });

    return idSalvo;
}
```

Since there's only one call to `child()` where pass a variable, it's clear that `getId()` is returning `null`, which is not allowed. You'll want to investigate why `id` is null.

---

Separate from that: this method is gonna return the old value of `idSalvo`, since by the time `return idSalvo` runs the `onComplete` hasn't been called yet. Run your code in a debugger, or add some logging lines, to most easily see this.

For more on this, read:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519)
- [Setting Singleton property value in Firebase Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203379/setting-singleton-property-value-in-firebase-listener)